# VBA to export data from a master file to multiple excel files

Tags: excel, vba

here is a code that I am using to extract data from multiple excel workbooks to a single master file. Now I need to reverse the process. That is, the data to be transferred from the master file to these multiple excel files. how to do that, please help.

I am a beginner in coding, I am self taught from internet.

"master" is the source file, from which data to be exported to all the other files in the folder

[image: "master" is the source file, from which data to be exported to all the other files in the folder]

master file

[image: master file]

template sample, red highlighted data to be obtained in that place from the source file

[image: template sample, red highlighted data to be obtained in that place from the source file]

code I have

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub copyfromsheet()

    Dim wkbkorigin As Workbook, destsheet As Worksheet
    Dim originsheet As Worksheet, RngDest As Range
    Dim Fname$

    Set destsheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

    Fname = Dir(ThisWorkbook.Path & "/*.xlsx*")

    'loop through each file in folder (excluding this one)
    Do While Fname <> "" And Fname <> ThisWorkbook.Name

        If Fname <> ThisWorkbook.Name Then

            Set wkbkorigin = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "/" & Fname)

            For Each originsheet In wkbkorigin.Sheets

                Set RngDest = destsheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp) _
                       .Offset(1, 0).EntireRow

                With RngDest
                    .Cells(1).Value = originsheet.Range("A10").Value 'vault
                    .Cells(2).Value = originsheet.Range("G9").Value 'date
                    .Cells(3).Value = originsheet.Range("E23").Value 'pickup
                    .Cells(4).Value = originsheet.Range("C21").Value 'refund
                    .Cells(5).Value = originsheet.Range("C13").Value 'load
                    .Cells(6).Value = originsheet.Range("H1").Value 'unload
                    .Cells(7).Value = originsheet.Range("H1").Value 'opening
                    .Cells(8).Value = originsheet.Range("H1").Value 'closing
                    .Cells(9).Value = wkbkorigin.Name 'wbk name H
                End With

            Next

            wkbkorigin.Close SaveChanges:=False   'close current file

        End If

        Fname = Dir()     'get next file
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: You will need to explain a bit more in detail how that export process would work - do the destination workbooks and worksheets already exist for example?  If not then how are they to be created and named?

Comment: @TimWilliams Workbooks already created with only one work sheet. Stored in same folder. I need only to export these data from the master file to each destination workbooks corresponding to the file names. (please see the sample photos attached)